Flutter items not aligned vertically in row
I cannot get a Text, IconButton and a Text to align vertically in a row.
I tried crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center without success.
This is the code of the row:
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Text(DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(wd.date!), style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16), textAlign: TextAlign.left),
    IconButton(
        iconSize: 17,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
        onPressed: wd.resetRequested ?? false ? null : () async {
          showConfirm(context, wd, reloadMonthCallback);
        },
        icon: Icon(Icons.delete)
    ),
    Text("${wd.totalHourCount.toStringAsFixed(2)}h", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 13), textAlign: TextAlign.right)
  ],
),

and this is the result:

Note: Using flutter web
Update: I tried using expanded and it looks good on desktop but still looks a bit unaligned in android (PWA not native android):


To align a Text, an IconButton, and another Text vertically in a Row, you can use the Expanded and Align widgets to ensure proper alignment. Here’s how you can modify your code:
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: Text(
          DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(wd.date!),
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    IconButton(
      iconSize: 17,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      onPressed: wd.resetRequested ?? false ? null : () async {
        showConfirm(context, wd, reloadMonthCallback);
      },
      icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: Text(
          "${wd.totalHourCount.toStringAsFixed(2)}h",
          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 13),
          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),


It works! I also managed to make them to expand vertically so they are centered, but only let one expand horizontally by setting flex 0 to the first one and flex 1 to the last one

okay so I deployed the changes and tried on the phone again (using the PWA version installed from chrome android) and it's still not centered, I'll update the question

okay remove the IconButtonPadding  and set it to 0 like this
padding: EdgeInsets.all(0)
will update the answer

I don't think this is the solution, this removes the padding around the icon (not button) meaning the circle it shows on hover would be very small and not look good. Also, since the padding goes all around the icon anyway, if the button is centered, it should not depend on its padding, should it?
